# Filezilla changes the file after upload

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I have this 63KB php file on a remote server. I'm using Filezilla to work on it. Until yesterday, I could open the file, make changes on it and then save it on the server. But now it started to change the file after saving and uploading back is complete. What it does to the file is: it copies like the first 100 lines and then pastes it till the file is 63KB. I tried changing transfer to binary from auto and restarting Filezilla(even my computer), it did not help.
Edit: I have this problem only with large files(like 60KB)

Comment: Check the remote server configuration (maximum file size, permissions, ...), it can be a lot of things, but is likely nothing related to filezilla.

Comment: _"open the file, make changes on it and then save it on the server"_ - that is not how you should develop software. Develop and test locally, push to staging to test and only then push to production. Anyway this doesn't sound like anything the FTP client or server would do. Are you sure the behavior you see is not caused by something else?

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: Martin, I have no idea how to do that :) lechariotdor, it is hosted on some server I do not have all the permissions on, I'll check with the support though. codecaster, it is not my production server but a development server, the reason I'm working on a remote server is that I have a group that I have been working together on this, and I do not want to struggle with integration of everybody's work. As far as I remember, I used smartFTP the problem does not exist on the other FTP software. I didn't change anything, all was working well and then this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the correct permissions are on the file and directories. It could be that the user account that you are trying to upload from doesn't have the correct permissions so the file isn't wrote.

Comment: I didn't change anything in any configuration, it suddenly happened. Thanks for the comment.